# update table in database dynamic php

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to update a table in my database with php. I have a function that calls all of the pages that are set to visible (visible = 1) in my database and lists them on the website. Each page has a radio button and if the radio button is set to yes (value = 1) then javascript calls a dropdown option. I want the user to be able to select their option and when they click the submit button for the information (page name and position number they have set it to) to insert into my table.

Here is the code below:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Perform Update

            $name = $_POST['visible_{$page["menu_name"]}'];
            $featured_position = $_POST['featured_position'];

            $query = "UPDATE pages SET 
                    featured_position = {$featured_position}
                    WHERE menu_name = {$name}";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            // test to see if the update occurred
            if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
                // Success!
                $message = "The page was successfully updated.";
            } else {
                $message = "The page could not be updated.";
                $message .= "<br />" . mysql_error();
            }

        }
?>

<?php if (!empty($message)) {
                echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";
} ?>

<form action="add_feature2.php" method="post">
<?php echo list_all_pages(); ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Featured Companies" />
</form>         

<?php
        function get_all_pages() {
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM pages ";
        $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
        $page_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($page_set);
        return $page_set;
    }

function list_all_pages(){
$output = "<ul>";
//$output .= $counter = 0;
$page_set = get_all_pages();
while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
$output .= "<li>{$page["menu_name"]}</li>";

$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id=\"$page[id]\" style='display: none'><select name='featured_position'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select></div>";

$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'none';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$page["menu_name"]} \" value=\"0\" checked=\"checked\" /> No <input onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'block';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$page["menu_name"]} \"value=\"1\" /> Yes";

//$output .= $counter = $counter+1;

    }
$output .= "</ul>";
return $output;
}   




?>
```

Here is a link to the website: http://www.firetreegraphics.com/widget_corp-final/add_feature2.php

**********************UPDATE************************************

I changed the name attribute on the radio buttons to be a counter. The reason I made the radio button name  attribute a variable is because I have dynamically created the radio buttons and each set of radio buttons has to have a unique name or else all of the sets are linked together.

```
$name = $_POST['{$counter}'];
            $featured_position = $_POST['featured_position'];

            $query = "UPDATE pages SET 
                    featured_position = '{$featured_position}'
                    WHERE menu_name = '{$name}'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
                            //echo($query);
                            var_dump($_REQUEST);


function list_all_pages(){
$output = "<ul>";
$counter = 0;
$page_set = get_all_pages();
while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
$output .= "<li>{$page["menu_name"]}</li>";

$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id=\"$page[id]\" style='display: none'><select name='featured_position'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select></div>";

$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'none';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"$counter\" value=\"0\" checked=\"checked\" /> No <input onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'block';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"$counter\" value=\"1\" /> Yes";

$counter = $counter+1;

    }
$output .= "</ul>";
return $output;
}
```

Comment: Output your sql to the screen before executing it and try running it in a tool like phpMyAdmin to figure out what's wrong ;)

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? A message saying it's updated but it hasn't? One saying it's not updated but it has?

Comment: @Terry. How would I output the sql to the screen before executing it?

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you need to quote out your variables:

```
 $query = "UPDATE pages SET  
      featured_position ='{$featured_position}'
      WHERE menu_name = '{$name}'";
```

**HOWEVER**

You should really look at moving to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. Not only will it help you write more secure code - you currently have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code - but it will take care of all the quoting for you.

Edit:

```
$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id=\"$page[id]\" style='display: none'><select name='featured_position_{$counter}'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select></div>";              
$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'none';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$counter}\" value=\"0\" checked=\"checked\" /> No <input onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'block';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$counter}\" value=\"1\" /> Yes";
```

I've renamed the radio buttons so that they're called 'visible_'; that will let you use the page's ID in your update query. I've also renamed the select, too, so each row has it's own select, called 'featured_position_'.

I think you're going to have to have a loop to check each value:

```
$page_set = get_all_pages();             
while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
    $id = $_POST["visible_" . $page["id"]];
    $featured_position = $_POST['featured_position_' . $page["id"];  

    $query = "UPDATE pages SET         
        featured_position = '{$featured_position}'        
        WHERE id = '{$name}'";
```

I *think* that that should be enough.

Comment: I put quotes around the $name and $featured_position and thought that would fix it b/c before I was getting a syntax error... but now i'm not even getting an error... it just says the page cannot be updated and does not give the mysql error.. any ideas why it still won't update...am i going about this completely wrong? For example, at the bottom I have the list_all_pages loop... am I trying to call the wrong thing when I hit the submit button or am I on the right track? Your help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Add an `echo($query)` before you execute it, and see what your query actually looks like.

Comment: @this is a really basic question... where should I put that line in?

Comment: Anywhere after you've created $query - you want to see what the SQL looks like, to make sure that it looks like when you expect it to look like.

Comment: UPDATE pages SET featured_position = '3' WHERE menu_name = ''

Comment: It's getting messed up on this line: $name = $_POST['visible_{$page["menu_name"]}']; 
... I have it calling the menu_name in the loop (where it calls the radio buttons) so that each of the radio buttons is seperate.. when I didn't have a dynamic element to this part it created the radio buttons but they were all connected and didn't have separate functioning.

Comment: @ristenk1 - check your HTML. I don't think that the HTML form is being generated right. If you want to see what you're getting passed in, try `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: I posted an update above b/c I changed the radio button's attribute "name" to a counter... I did the var_dump but don't understand it: array(6) { ["featured_position"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" ["submit"]=> string(23) "Edit Featured Companies" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "fquvqglus0ljjgq1ar4tdbcf76" }  Do you know how to decipher this? I will also check the html but would you mind clarifying a little more? Thank you so much!!

Comment: I edited the above to change the radio button's name at attribute to a counter variable but I think it's still got the same problem. Here is the result of var_dump: array(6) { ["featured_position"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" ["submit"]=> string(23) "Edit Featured Companies" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "" } ...I don't know what it means, do you? Also, you mentioned before a problem with the html, can you explain?

Comment: @ristenk1 - I've added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the PHP mysql API is deprecated and largely "un-recommended". You should use MySQLi, well you don't have to, but its pretty much the same, which is why I suggest it.

When I first looked I saw this problem in one of your queries:

```
  "UPDATE pages SET 
  featured_position = {$featured_position}
  WHERE menu_name = {$name}";
```

Presumably `{$name}` is a string. SO your query ends with `WHERE menu_name = string` whereas it should be encased in quote marks.

```
  "UPDATE pages SET 
  featured_position = {$featured_position}
  WHERE menu_name = '{$name}' ";
```

Comment: I put quotes around the $name and $featured_position and thought that would fix it b/c before I was getting a syntax error... but now i'm not even getting an error... it just says the page cannot be updated and does not give the mysql error.. any ideas why it still won't update...am i going about this completely wrong? For example, at the bottom I have the list_all_pages loop... am I trying to call the wrong thing when I hit the submit button or am I on the right track? Your help is very appreciated. Thank you!